# How to disable gradle build to start automatically when change build variant

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

How to disable gradle build to start automatically when change build variant in Android Strudio 1.4 ?

Comment: could you explain it better?

Comment: When I switch from build variant release to debug and  viceversa , gradle build start automatically, I want to start this manually ?

Comment: Changing the build variant you can have some changes in your code due to your build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck **Configure on Demand** option

[image]